# Add a product for all users based on a condition (WooCommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users

Hello everyone in my wordpress website, I want to add a product to all users based on a condition, I mean if a condition is true I will inform specific users and then add the product for them, how can I do it?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/423906/edit) to include the code you're trying to use. Without seeing your code, we have no way of knowing how to help you. (Note that third-party plugins, like WooCommerce, are [off topic](/help/on-topic) here, and you should contact their support teams for questions specific to the plugin.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.